# When right click, explorer automatically restarts

Tags: windows, explorer, restart

I'm having a trouble with Right-Click, Ctrl+C, Ctrl+V...
when I did one of above any where on my windows box, it just restarts the explorer.exe.
Help me to resolve this.

Thank You!

Comment: You should provide some code. If this is a normal Windows issue (not a coding project) then you should try a different forum.

Comment: I just happened. I have no idea what is the reason. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a Shell Extension that is crashing explorer.

Use [ShellExView](http://nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html)  to find and disable it.

Comment: Thanks. I resolved it (temporarily) using this tool. One of these under  HKCR\*\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\??? may be the case. Some how my svn entry of the right-click menu was crashed.